# How to reduce the time taken by an ADF pipeline to read all the files in a FileShare and pick only the latest file

Tags: file, azure-data-factory, last-modified, azure-file-share

We daily receive files to fileShare and it increases number of files save in that folder. So, ADF pipeline takes lot of time to pick the latest file. I want to know how to reduce the time that pipeline takes to go through all the files in the folder. Thank you!

This is the overview of my pipelines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQoCw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXuzw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfXqi.png)

Comment: what is your folder structure? are the files in nested level? What is your blocker here?

Comment: Generally the way I'd deal with this is to archive the files that have been processed/don't need to be processed into another folder.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Pipeline took around 20 minutes run and check all the files in the folder. There are daily files from August this year.  So Pipeline reads each file one by one to select the latest file. I want to know whether there is any method to reduce this time takes. It is a Folder file Structure and files are not in nested level

Comment: @Nipz, Is every time only one file will be uploaded or simultaneously all uploading at same time? it means what is the time interval between two file uploads?

Comment: No, per day per file. But folder has all the history files. So pipeline checks all the files to select the latest files.

Answer (score 0):

On your initial Get Metadata activity (Get file List), limit the files only to those modified in the last day:

[image: metadata activity]

where start time is 24 hours ago:

```
@subtractFromTime(utcnow(),1440,'Minute')
```

and end time is now:

```
utcnow()
```

Since you want to find the latest file, bringing only files modified in last 24 hours will reduce the number of iteration in the foreach activity and improve run times.

Comment: Chen Hirsh,

Thank you, Your answer works, when I added utcnow() for end time, it failed and got this error '
Field 'childItems' failed with error: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value 'utcnow()' in 'modifiedDatetimeEnd' property to 'System.Nullable,      Then I removed the EndTime and executed and it worked. Do you see any error of using only the Start Time?

Comment: @Nipz, empty end time means no end time, which works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @[**Chen Hirsh**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21079004/chen-hirsh), **as your file uploading will be one file per everyday**, Get meta data activity will give only one file(latest uploaded file) in the child items array.

So, no need to use the For loop to determine the latest file, you can directly use the Get meta data activity output for the latest file name.

Use the same expression for the start time as above answer. For end time, use `@utcnow()` to avoid the above error. After Get meta data activity use copy activity like below.

[image]

Use the below expression for the filename. Use dataset parameter in the source dataset for the filename and give the below expression for that parameter.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0].name
```

**NOTE:** This works only when the time difference between your file uploads is 24 hours. If it changes you need to change the start time expression as per the time interval.

Comment: Hi Rakesh,if we get list of files from Get Metadata1 and if we want to pick only the last modified file, how can we adjust the logic? because now 'childItems[0]' gives the oldest file

Comment: You mentioned that only one file will be uploaded for every 24 hours. My solution gives that one file in the array and childItems[0] is that file only which is uploaded in the last 24 hours. Read the note above. If the time interval between two uploads changes then change the start time dynamic expression according to that time.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. I just want to know if we have list of files in that time period, is there any expression to get the latest file, E.g childItems[-1] something like this

Comment: No. the items in Get meta data array will come as sorted by the file name not by the last modified. We cannot say ChildItem[last] is the latest modified if it gives list of files. If it gives list of files, then your loop approach is the correct solution to find the latest file.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I am going to try the loop solution.